# Spring: Injecting property as a value into an annotation

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, spring-aop

I am trying to inject a value into a Custom Annotation but Spring doesn't seem to be evaluating.

Here is my annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnno {
    String var1();
    String var2();
}
```

Here is my Bean (it is created in a Spring Configuration file) with Annotation:

```
public class MyClass {

    @MyCustomAnno(var1 = "${some.property.one}",
                  var2 = "${some.property.two}")
    public void someMethod() {
    // do something here
    }
}
```

Here is the Aspect where I am trying to use the values passed into the annotation:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAop {

    @Around(value="@annotation(myCustomAnno)",argNames="myCustomAnno")
    public Object aroundMethod(MyCustomAnno myCustomAnno) {
        int intVar1 = Integer.parseInt(myCustomAnno.var1());
        int intVar2 = Integer.parseInt(myCustomAnno.var2());

        // ....
    }
}
```

In the around method I am receiving a NumberFormatException: For input string: ${some.property.one}. This means that Spring didn't inject the value for some reason.

In case you are wondering, in the same class I can do the normal @Value annotation and the value gets injected properly:

```
@Value("${some.property.one}")
private propertyOne;            // This works
```

Is it possible to do what I want to and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, placeholders are not resolved in custom annotations. However you could resolve them in the Aspect itself.

For example:

```
@Aspect
class MyAop implements EmbeddedValueResolverAware {

    private StringValueResolver resolver;

    @Around(value="@annotation(myCustomAnno)",argNames="myCustomAnno")
    public void play(MyCustomAnno ann) {
        System.out.println(resolver.resolveStringValue(ann.var1()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setEmbeddedValueResolver(StringValueResolver resolver) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }
}
```